# Не работает ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM `order` 
WHERE `status_id` =3
AND `finish_datetime` < ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) 
GROUP BY `user_id` 
HAVING count( `user_id` ) >1
ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

есть такой запрос,почему то на `ORDER BY CREATED DESC(или ASC-без разницы)` не обращается никакого внимания, 1 стоит то у кого меньший `id`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by), может быть поможет!